# Node JS request - How to make the response body available for all other JS

Tags: node.js, request

Please refer the below code to invoke a web service. The response is available in 'body' within the callback.

For my application, I would want to invoke the web service once and use the same 'body' json in multiple JS files. How can this be achieved?

```
var req = request(host, options,(error, response, body) => {
if(error!=null)
{
console.log(error);
}
console.log(body);
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try Promise feature

```
var globalBodyResponse = new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {   
     resolve(globalBody);   
});
var req = request(host, options,(error, response, body) => {
    if(error) {
     console.log(error);
    }
    globalBody = body;
});

// somewhere else in your application
globalBodyResponse.then(function(result) {   
  console.log(result); });
```

Answer (score 0):

You may want to create a global variable and assign the value of the body to the global variable when available.

For example:

```
var globalBody = null;
var req = request(host, options,(error, response, body) => { 
if(error!=null) 
{ 
console.log(error); 
} 
globalBody = body;
console.log(body); 
});
// Now you have the globalBody available to use anywhere.
```

Comment: Im getting globalBody as null if I print it outside the function

Comment: It wont be populated until your callback is successful.

Comment: Yes, callback is successful. i get the value printed if I print right after globalBody = body. But, if I print somewhere else, I get null

Comment: You should wait for callback to finish and then only use the globalBody. Checkout async/await or promises.

Comment: Thanks!! I wrapped it around a promise and used await at caller to synchronize. When I print body, I get the entire json. When I print globalBody in another function, I just see {Object object} getting printed. Any idea how to get the entire json